# Form append just VALUES not variables to URL

Tags: php, jquery, forms, url

I need to send a Form with just the values append to the URL, like this:

> http://thisistheurl.com/serv#search/**VALUE1**/**VALUE2**/**VALUE3**/**VALUE4**

I could send like this:

> http://thisistheurl.com/serv?**variable1=value**&**variable2=value**&**variable3=value**&**variable4=value**#search/

The form is very simple.

```
<form id="consultatickets" name="consultatickets" role="form" method="get" class="tickets-form" action="http://thisistheurl.com/serv#search/" target="_blank">

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <label for="ciudadorigen" class="tickets-imputs">Ciudad de Origen</label>
        <select name="ciudadorigen" class="form-control ciudadorigen tickets-imputs" for="ciudadorigen">
            <option selected disabled>1</option>
            <option value="562">2</option>
            <option value="582">3</option>
        </select>                   
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Here goes the rest of the form -->

<a type="submit" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect btn-block" href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('consultatickets').submit();">Buscar <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

I don't know how to extract the just the values from the variables and append to the URL.

Comment: It is not clear from your example what Variable you are referring to. If you want to capture the data and remap it in the URL, you will need to do this without making use of the default functions of the HTML Form. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The variable it's the name of the **INPUT** or **SELECT**. HTML form always append like this: ?inputname=inputvalue&... . I onlu need the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter, you can achieve this by serializing the values of the form and appending it to the action attribute of the form to build the final url.

```
<form id="consultatickets" name="consultatickets" role="form" method="get" class="tickets-form" action="http://thisistheurl.com/serv#search" target="_blank">

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <label for="ciudadorigen" class="tickets-imputs">Ciudad de Origen</label>
        <select name="ciudadorigen" class="form-control ciudadorigen tickets-imputs" for="ciudadorigen">
            <option selected disabled>1</option>
            <option value="562">2</option>
            <option value="582">3</option>
        </select>
        <label for="campo_adicional">Campo adicional</label>
        <input id="campo_adicional" type="text" name="campo_adicional" />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>

$("#consultatickets").on('submit',
function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var values = $(this).serializeArray();
  var baseUrl = $(this).prop("action");
  $.each(values, function(i, v) {
    baseUrl += "/" + encodeURIComponent(v.value);
  });
  alert(baseUrl);
}
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kb3rvLjs/

Comment: Yes, the order matter. I'll try this option. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work. The fiddle works fine, I copy from there but nothing. I change the way i'm doing. Thanks you a lot.

Comment: How do you modify your code and what "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It's a jquery problem with conflict. I change the "$" to "jQuery" and works i the Alert. The alert shows the correct URL, but I can't send. It never submt the form, I stay in the same page, instead or going to the form submit URL.

Comment: Solved. I add **window.open(baseUrl, '_blank');** and thats send me to the URL I want.

Answer (score 0):

Untested and I'm not sure if I got your question correctly but it seems you look for something like this:

```
// your form submit event handler
function formSubmit() {
    var form = $('#consultatickets');
    // build your url
    var url = 'http://thisistheurl.com/serv#search/' + 
        getValues(form).join('/');

    // redirect to your new location
    location.href = url;
};

// function to get the values from the form elements
function getValues(form) {
    // get all form fields in the form
    var fields = $( "input, select", form);
    var values = [];
    // loop over the fields, add them to array
    jQuery.each( fields, function( field ) {
      values.push(encodeURI(field.val()));
    });
    return values;
}
```

In case you want to trigger the form submit with the a tag, simply change your onclick attribute to: `onclick ="formSubmit();"`.

Comment: I'm gonna try, but I think you are on the right way.

Comment: I don't know how to call the function. In form action i put **action="getValues();"** and in the submit **onclick="document.getElementById('consultatickets').submit();"** but doesn't work.

Comment: @Estudio3551 no - you do it wrong. I have updated my answer - are you sure you are using jQuery? The concept with an inline onclick is not the common jQuery way, neither the document.getElementById. Anyway, you can't use a javascript method as an action for a form.

Comment: Thanks for your time!!